# Watering a Four Seasons Lemon Tree

Tags: fruit-trees, watering, lemons

I think that I am having problems with watering on my lemon tree as well. Unfortunately, I don't know if I am overwatering it or under-watering it...It looks like it is underwatered as the new branches do not look healthy. However, when I touch the soil it is moist and the branches start to look healthier at the evening. I have re-planted the tree in a new pot recently and I have used a different soil. Could it be that the soil from the previous container has better drainage and does not hold water (the tree is underwatered)? All the fruit have fallen, but now it is blooming. Please help :)[image]